# GetUsageData() in a web part returns null

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, webpartpage

I am trying to display some SharePoint usage data in a web part.

Here's my code:

```
SPSite spSiteCollection = new SPSite(myURL)
spSiteCollection.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
SPWeb spWeb = spSiteCollection.OpenWeb();

DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();
dtResults = spWeb.GetUsageData(SPUsageReportType.url, SPUsagePeriodType.lastMonth);
```

The DataTable that is supposed to contain the results is always null. I also tried to run this from an aspx page but nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I think before you can retrieve any usage data you have to configure your farm and [activate usage reporting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541.aspx).

Comment: i did configure the usage reporting from both the Administration site and the SSP site, also activated the feature in my SharePoint site.